# photon and Z boson interference?

Tags: interference, virtual-particles, bosons

I'm not certain that this question will make sense, but here goes...

In most monte carlo generators, when Z events are produced, there is a lower mass cutoff on the Z pole. I've been told that this is because the interference term with the photon would otherwise cause a divergence if you have $\gamma \to ee$ with low invariant mass.

Can anybody explain the meaning of this statement?

Comment: It is certainly the case that there is an interference term; $G^0$ and some other projects have measured it.